# Printing yearwise popular movies from csv in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a collection of movie data in an Excel format. It has columns with year, title, and popularity. My goal is to create a dataframe with yearwise movies with top popularity. For now I am able to create only the year and the popularity rating. I want to add the movie title too.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
xd=data.groupby(['release_year']).max()['popularity']
xf=pd.DataFrame(xd)
xd.head(100)
```

Output:

```
1960     2.610362
1961     2.631987
1962     3.170651
```

I also want the movie name along with this.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to transform the index.

Let's say this is your data:

```
release_year, popularity, movie
1999, 5, a
1999, 4, c
2000, 3, b
2000, 4, d
```

Do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
data= pd.read_csv('data.csv')
idx = data.groupby(['release_year'])['popularity'].transform(max) == data['popularity']
```

The result of `data['popularity']` be:

```
release_year popularity movie
1999  5 a
2000 4 b
```

Comment: thank you so much, but printing the dataframe gives this kind of output for me        0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False